# useState calls error Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When I use **setMiddle(true)** it getting an error "Too many re-renders.."

Can you please tell me why?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [ test, setTest ] = useState(true)
  const [ test1, setTest1 ] = useState(false)
  const [ middle, setMiddle ] = useState(false)

  const setFrame = () => {
    console.log('123')
    setTest1(false)
  }

  const titleScreen = () => {        

    setMiddle(true)
    setFrame('myRoom');

    return
  }

  const renderFrame = () => {
    return (<div>Ta-daa!</div>)
  }


  return (
    <div>
        {test1 ? renderFrame() : null}
        {test ? titleScreen() : null}
    </div>
  )
}


export default App
```

But when I deleting the line **setMiddle(true)** and **setTest1(false)** it works

Comment: You should avoid setting state in the render-method (return (<div>...</div>)). In this case you check if state variable "test" is true, if so you alter state with setMiddle and setTest1, which will trigger a re-render. Try to decide what to render outside of the render method and you should be able to get it working as intended

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `test` is true at the beginning, so `titleScreen()` is called, and inside that function, you mutate the state which fires a re-render, and since `test` never changes its value, it calls again `titleScreen()` and then you fall in the phantom zone called The Infinite Loop.

How you prevent it? always mutate the state when something happens in your application, a user interaction, an API call, etc. never do it on page render, or if you do it, make sure you break the condition, in this case change `test` value at some point.